# Does there exist an injective homomorphism $\phi : \Bbb G_a \to \Bbb G_m$?

Tags: proof-verification, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field.  $\Bbb G_a$ is the Linear algebraic group with the underlying variety being $\Bbb A = k$ with the additive group operation . $\Bbb G_m$ is the Linear algebraic group with the underlying variety being $\Bbb A^*$ with the multiplicative group operation.

The question is :

> Does there exist an injective homomorphism $\phi : \Bbb G_a \to \Bbb G_m$ ?

My attempt :

No!

Let $\phi \in Hom(\Bbb G_a,\Bbb G_m)$ .

Then that will induce a $k$-algebra  homomorphism from the Coordinate ring of $\Bbb G_m$ to the Coordinate ring of $\Bbb G_a$ i.e. $\phi ^* : \frac{k[X,Y]}{(XY-1)} \to k[T]$ i.e. $\phi ^* :  k[X,X^{-1}] \to k[T]$ .

$X$ is a unit in $ k[X,X^{-1}]$ , hence $\phi^*(X)$ must be a unit in $k[T]$  . But ${k[T]}^* = k^*$ thus $\phi^*(X)=c \text{ (say)}\in k^*$ , but that will fail the injectivity of $\phi^*$ since $c \in k[X,X^{-1}]$ and $\phi^*(c)=c$ .

Are my arguments valid? Please point out mistakes if any.

Comment: Yes. You can see that you have not used the group structure at all. What you have shown (correctly) is that there are no non-constant morphism $\mathbb{A}^1\to \mathbb{A}^1-\{0\}$.

Comment: No, I said you were correct. Only additional thing I said was the statement that you proved is more general and group structure was never used in your proof.

Comment: (in terms of coordinate rings, what Mohan is saying is that you only used the "$k$-algebra" structure on them, not their Hopf-algebra structure arising from the group structure)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to get this off the unanswered list: **no**. There do not exist injective homomorphisms $\mathbb{G}_a\to\mathbb{G}_m$ as your concrete calculation shows. In fact, there exists no non-trivial homomorphisms $\mathbb{G}_a\to \mathbb{G}_m$ since the image would then be isomorphic to $\mathbb{G}_a$ (since all quotients of $\mathbb{G}_a$ are isomorphic to itself) and thus we would have produced an injective homomorphism $\mathbb{G}_a\to\mathbb{G}_m$.

Two more general comments:

1. If $f:G\to H$ is an injective homomorphism of algebraic groups, then it's actually a closed embedding (e.g. see [Mil, Corollary 3.3.5]) and so if $G$ and $H$ are of the same dimension (and $H$ is reduced), then it's an isomorphism!
2. There are no non-trivial homomorphism $\mathbb{G}_a\to\mathbb{G}_m$ over any ring $R$ that is reduced, but if $R$ contains a non-zero element $x$ such that $x^2=0$ then there are non-trivial homomorphisms $\mathbb{G}_a\to\mathbb{G}_m$ (try to find them!).

Comment: An excellent and useful answer, especially the last bit. :)

Comment: @paulgarrett Thanks very much for your kind words! I have benefitted from your expositions many times over the years, so thank you for that as well!

Comment: :) ..............